# The bullet points on github tag is wrong (the second item is always a subitem from the first)

Tags: git, github

I trying to create a bullet point list on github tag message, but in all the cases, the second item is always the subitem from the first (but they are on the same level).

My message:

```
 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
 - Fusce a dui sit amet sapien gravida fermentum sit amet sed lacus.
 - Morbi eget nisi eget leo imperdiet varius sit amet non leo.
 - Aliquam maximus eros id posuere aliquam.
 - Integer id nisl vitae lacus maximus pharetra non ac justo.
 - In pellentesque nibh non congue ornare.
```

What is prompt on github:

[image: prompt on github]

I already try a few ways (with and without spaces, extra spaces, breaking lines, etc), but the result is always the same.

Does someone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

In short, this looks like a bug on GitHub.

First of all, this isn't an HTML or Markdown list. GitHub just tries (but fails) to display the content of the tag message verbatim.

In your list, it seems that you have spaces at the start of every line. This doesn't seem to affect the bug in question, though. Also, your tag messages are missing a subject line. But even with subject line, GitHub doesn't seem to handle tag message very well.

Here's how my attempt at reproducing your issue looks like on the page of the singular tag:

[image: display of a tag without a subject line]

But with a subject line and without spaces at the start of lines it looks like this:

[image: display of a tag with a subject line]

Listing of tags looks broken, like in your screenshot:

[image: demonstration of the bug with two tags]

In a terminal, the tags look like this:

```
tag tmp-tag
Tagger: andrybak <example@example.com>
Date:   2023-05-04T19:59:53+00:00

 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
 - Fusce a dui sit amet sapien gravida fermentum sit amet sed lacus.
 - Morbi eget nisi eget leo imperdiet varius sit amet non leo.
 - Aliquam maximus eros id posuere aliquam.
 - Integer id nisl vitae lacus maximus pharetra non ac justo.
 - In pellentesque nibh non congue ornare.
```

```
tag tmp-tag-2
Tagger: andrybak <example@example.com>
Date:   2023-05-04T20:00:10+00:00

Temporary version

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
- Fusce a dui sit amet sapien gravida fermentum sit amet sed lacus.
- Morbi eget nisi eget leo imperdiet varius sit amet non leo.
- Aliquam maximus eros id posuere aliquam.
- Integer id nisl vitae lacus maximus pharetra non ac justo.
- In pellentesque nibh non congue ornare.
```